# Enable PHP extension for Apache instead CLI

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache, shell

I'm building a bootstrap.sh file for a Vagrant setup and I need a simple way (bash command if possible) to enable a few extensions of PHP but when I run `phpenmod` it enable the extension for `/etc/php/7.x/cli/php.ini` but I want to enable in `/etc/php/7.x/apache2/php.ini`.

What should I do?

Comment: just install it, and if its not a custom extension it will enable itself

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/enable-disable-php-modules-ubuntu/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it works! If it was an answer I would approve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the options:

```
$ phpenmod
WARNING: 
usage: phpenmod [ -v ALL|php_version ] [ -s ALL|sapi_name ] module_name [ module_name_2 ]
```

You can use `-s sapi_name` to choose which SAPI to enable an extension for, so `phpenmod -s apache2 <extname>` should do it.

Although, the default should be `ALL`, so I don't see why it hasn't worked for you so far without this. Maybe you forgot to restart Apache or PHP-FPM before checking if the extension is enabled? Double-check.